# How to make numbers 'human readable' in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Is there a mysql parameter that adds in commas to make reading a large number easier?

For example:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable;
100,293,493,444 # instead of "100293493444"
```

Comment: no, there isn't. it isn't mysql's job to make things "easy" for you - it's job is to store data, and efficiently retrieve it. Making things human readable is a client-side issue.

Comment: "Reading a large number easier" Where are you reading this number?

Comment: @MarcB: MySQL actually has a lot of built-in functions :-)

Comment: **"If it was hard to write, it should be hard to use."** - unknown

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`FORMAT` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_format).

```
SELECT FORMAT(COUNT(*), 0) AS count FROM myTable; -- 100,293,493,444
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the MySQL **`FORMAT`** function.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_format

```
SELECT COUNT(*)           AS cnt
     , FORMAT(COUNT(*),0) AS fmt_cnt
  FROM myTable;
```

returns e.g.

```
cnt           fmt_cnt
------------  ---------------
100293493444  100,293,493,444
```

**NOTE:** The value returned from the FORMAT function is *not* a number, it's a string.

That means that if you try to add something to that value, for example:

```
 SELECT FORMAT(12345,0) + 30
```

What you'll get back is **`42`**.

That's because in a *numeric* context, the *string* value returned by the `FORMAT` function (in this example, it would be `'12,345'`) gets re-interpreted as a number. And MySQL doesn't throw an error when it runs into the comma or some character it doesn't understand, it just stops with the value that it has, which results in a numeric value of 12.